# Issue writing strings to a file

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>

#define KEYSIZE 16


int main(){
  FILE *fptr;

  fptr = fopen("program.txt", "w");

  if (fptr == NULL) {
      printf("Error!");
      exit(1);
  }

  int num_keys = 1524006529 - 1523999329;
  const char *keys[num_keys];
  int idx = 0;
  int j;

  for (j = 1523999329; j<= 1524006529; j++){
    int i;
    char key[KEYSIZE];
    srand (j); 
    for (i = 0; i< KEYSIZE; i++){
      key[i] = rand()%256;
      printf("%.2x", (unsigned char)key[i]);
      fprintf(fptr, "%.2x", (unsigned char)key[i]);
    }
    fprintf(fptr, "%s", "\n");
    printf("\n");
    keys[idx] = key;
    idx ++;
  }
  fclose(fptr);
  return 0;

}
```

I want to create a text file (program.txt) that has a new string key variable on each line. The code above produces a txt file that has this content though:

```
h?G??+?
Mp???+??
        a?G????#*Jb`e0?H?????G??????
S6&}?Μ??G??OFf??|???s8f?G????ɼ???5q??(???K?G??  ??J????9?+???G?????cZ?n0?Jr?G?????#O9]??????jH??G???krT?̇)?A
                             ?g?v?G??????h^(?^?
                                               û/?G???^vB?~W?39???G??\????"?iJ_????G??p??>??????I???U?G????????:??o?RV???G??/?C?^?????|?۬?G??q@0.L$+??Nv?????G????u?    L?Ϩ????dv?G??[??C｢<??i???G??UyM??Ƭ/??CxXUě?G?????φ
                                                          ׏:W&?G????=J???o???I??G???G%DA+"?~5?Z¡?G??øL#??O=e?b?u.O?G????*jjɥ+T?)?օ?G??2w  }a,ȃ??tC?s?G??J"/c??Mn???f?y??G????p?Ay?c????~"<?G?????Ӆ?=%??@???G??o?\??<w???4WϚBE?G??}oh??(??#HK???&?G????Vfz
???e?s?G??/?Ye??iV?؛?,-te?G??I?Ҁx??5?B!b?4?G??6Z??9?P?GcB?}???Y?~|"??dd??G??????=?ms?
    ??G?????^??[H??\:???G??2(J??A??????G???????o#?i?/???G??P?5?5?5X??
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `char key[KEYSIZE];` ... 16 bytes ... `keys[idx] = key;` ranges up to 7200 bytes... You are scribbling outside of your array... Why are you using such bizarre constant integer numbers?

Comment: @Fe2O3 Why would the array impact whats written inside the file though? I'm wrtting each digit with fprintf(fptr, "%.2x", (unsigned char)key[i]);? Even if i remove the array completely the file still looks unreadable? Also I know the numbers are ridiculous, this is for a project :/

Comment: I've copied and compiled and run your code... It works fine for me writing 7200 lines of 32bytes of 'hex' to the screen and into the file... right up until it tries to store the 7201st copy of the address of the local variable `key` into the collection `keys[]` that is dimensioned for 7200 copies of that address... A wild guess might be that your compiler (and buffered output to a file) mean that this overrun has corrupted a critical location, causing printf to go slightly insane... Fix the overrun. And use 7200 in the code. Add the bizarre lower value if you need to.

Comment: (ctd:) You probably want `<`, not `<=` in this line: `for (j = 1523999329; j<= 1524006529;`

Comment: Are on Windows, Linux or Mac?